# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAdmin') JWT token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, sequelize.js, token

I'm trying to develop a verifyTokenAdmin middleware, however when testing in my postman, it is returned to me error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAdmin') JWT token
```

I would like to have a token for a check if isAdmin is true, and consequently authenticate my route. In theory in the user I don't have null, pos isAdmin starts as false by default.

middleware

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const { authorization } = req.headers;

    if (!authorization) {
        return res.status(401).json('Invalid Authorization')
    };

    const token = authorization.replace('Bearer', ' ').trim();

    try {
        const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
        const data = jwt.verify(token, secret);

        const { id } = data;

        req.userId = id;  
        
        return next();
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json(err);
    }
  };

    verifyAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.Users.isAdmin) {
            next();
        } else {
            return res.status(403).json("You are not alowed to do that!");
        }
    }

module.exports = {
  verifyToken,
  verifyAdmin,
};
```

route

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const CreateUserController = require('../controllers/UserController/CreateUser');
const FindAllUsersController = require('../controllers/UserController/FindAllUsers');

const { verifyToken, verifyAdmin } = require('../middlewares/verifyToken');

router.post('/', CreateUserController.store);
router.get('/', verifyToken, verifyAdmin, FindAllUsersController.index);
module.exports = router;
```

model user

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  User.init({
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    phoneNumber: DataTypes.STRING,
    isAdmin: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

The table is saved as "Users" in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one line in your middleware file:

```
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const { authorization } = req.headers;

    if (!authorization) {
        return res.status(401).json('Invalid Authorization')
    };

    const token = authorization.replace('Bearer', ' ').trim();

    try {
        const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
        const data = jwt.verify(token, secret);
        req.users = data; //add this new line in your code

        const { id } = data;

        req.userId = id;  
        
        return next();
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: The error persists

Comment: Have you tried logging your `data` returned after jwt decoding?